# Javascript countdown and redirect - Part 2

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have a webpage that runs a JavaScript modal popup box with a message in it informing the visitor that they will be redirected to our new site in XX seconds. It also has two links saying "Agree" (then they are redirected) and "Disagree" (to stay on the old/current website).

This all seems to work fine but what I want it to do is stop the redirect when the user either clicks the Disagree link and/or when they click the darkened area outside the popup box (called `#mask`).

How can I get this to work? - the JS code is below.

Here is the popup box JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if Disagree word is clicked
$('#disagree').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
    $('#mask').hide();
}); 

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

});
```

And here is the countdown timer code (which is not external like the above popup.js but in the page itself):

`<script src="popup.js"></script>`

```
var time_left = 12;
var cinterval;

function time_dec(){
time_left--;
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
if(time_left == 1){
    var originalstring = document.getElementById('countdown2').innerHTML;
    var newstring = originalstring.replace('seconds','second');
    document.getElementById('countdown2').innerHTML = newstring;
    window.location.replace("http://cadfemukandireland.com/");
    clearInterval(cinterval);
}
}

cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
```

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="boxes">
<div id="dialog" class="window">
<p>We are currently in the process of upgrading our current website to a new and improved version.</p>
<p>You will automatically be directed to the new website <span id="countdown2">in <span id="countdown">12</span> seconds</span>.</p>
<div id="popupfoot"> <a href="http://cadfemukandireland.com/" >I agree</a> |    <a id="disagree" style="color:red;">I disagree</a> </div>
</div>
<div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have a timer if you're waiting for the user to agree/disagree? You could even just use e.g. `confirm('stay or go')`

Comment: I think because if the user doesn't make a choice then we will just redirect them anyway. But it's a thought, if I can't get it to work then I might haver no choice but to use your suggestion but that wouldn't be ideal as it's not what the boss wants.

Comment: Plus that function would use a dialog box but I want to keep my popup. The test page can be found here: http://www.idac.co.uk/index3.htm

Comment: added new answer @alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below - It basically zeros the time left when disagree is clicked

I've also assigned the `time_dec` function to a variable for easier scoping

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

  //if Disagree word is clicked
  $('#disagree').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
    $('#mask').hide();
    time_left = 0;
  }); 

  //if mask is clicked
  $('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });     

});

var time_left = 3;
var cinterval;

document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;

var time_dec = function(){
 time_left--;
 document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
 if(time_left == 1){
   var originalstring = document.getElementById('countdown2').innerHTML;
   var newstring = originalstring.replace('seconds','second');
   document.getElementById('countdown2').innerHTML = newstring;
   window.location.replace("http://cadfemukandireland.com/");
   clearInterval(cinterval);
 }
}

cinterval = setInterval(time_dec, 1000);
```

```css
#dialog {
 position: absolute;
 width: 300px;
 height: 220px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 16px;
 top: 100px;
 left: 100px;
 z-index: 999;
 background: #fff;
}
#mask {
 z-index: 9;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="boxes">
 <div id="dialog" class="window">
  <p>We are currently in the process of upgrading our current website to a new and improved version.</p>
  <p>You will automatically be directed to the new website <span id="countdown2">in <span id="countdown">12</span> seconds</span>.</p>
  <div id="popupfoot"> <a href="http://cadfemukandireland.com/">I agree</a> |    <a id="disagree" style="color:red;">I disagree</a> 
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That hasn't worked..the timer isn't counting down at all, the disagree link down't do anything now, and it's using what looks like a dialog box and not the model popup box that was there before and the background went dark. Here it is with you above code http://www.idac.co.uk/index3.htm

Comment: Did you click the `Run code snippet` link? It counts down until you click the `disagree` link or reaches 0. You didn't provide any css so I made it up with the mask/dialog box - this definitely works

Comment: Hi Darren, you were right, I used my own css and its all now working perfectly. Thank you for all your help, time and patients.

Comment: Hi Darren, is there a way to run the above just once when a user visits the site and not every time they go to a page?

Comment: Yeah I'd drop a cookie on the user if that's what you want - call it whatever you want and then check if that cookie exists, if it does do nothing